# Вернуть ссылку на локальную переменную, а может rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, ссылки, const, параметры

*Глобально перефразирую вопрос. С предисловием.*
Есть класс-контейнер-обёртка, в котором хранится нечтно типа `T` или `value_type`. Этот класс именуется `Параметр` и обеспечиает доступ к `value_` через геттеры и сеттеры.

```
template<typename T> 
class Parameter{ 
private: 
  T value_ = default_value();
public:
  virtual T& get();
  virtual T& set();
  virtual const T& default_value();
}
```

Другой класс наследует Parameter, переопределяя геттер, сеттер, и значение_по_умолчанию. Как-то так

Ищу способ сделать, **чтобы вновь созданные объекты унаследованного класса заполнялись дефолтным значением**. Как-то так:

```
struct ParA : Parameter<ClassA> {
     virtual const ClassA& default_value{ return ClassA{33}; }
} mypar;
assert( mypar.value_ == ClassA{33}; )  //должно прокатить
```

Важен вопрос оптимальности, и избежание лишних копий. Тут также возникают трудности с наследованием конструктора. Но это, полагаю, другой вопрос.

---

#### было и правда сумбурно (спойлер-бы-сюда)

*Оставил этот текст, потому как ответы уже написаны.*
*Нет такой фичи*(думал есть) возвращать ссыль на локальный объект. Удобно если его недолго использовать (короткое время жизни).

```
template<typename T>
const T& local_ref()
{ return T(); }
```

Это **НЕ**допустимо. Я хочу использовать такую фишку, чтобы получать времменый объект. Например (псевдокод):

```
template<T> class Parameter {
     Parameter() : value_(default_value());
     T value_;  // а может T value_=default_value(); без конструктора
     virtual const T& default_value(){ return T(); }
}
struct ParA : Parameter<ClassA> {
     virtual const ClassA& default_value{ return ClassA{33}; }
} mypar;
assert( mypar.value_ == ClassA{33}; )
```

Чего я собственно хочу добится. Чтобы в новые объекты класса ParA заливались объекты по умолчанию. Это например. Реализуемо. Кстати нет ли тут подводных камней? Но, если объект большой, то объект сначала сконструируется, а потом будет копироваться. Так? Возникает вопрос как бы это дело написать красиво и правильно и оптимально? Не поможет ли тут rvalue-ссылка?

Comment: "красиво и правильно и оптимально" - pick two :)

Comment: на сколько это возможно со всей объективностью...

Comment: А вы уверены на счет *"допустимо возвращать ссыль на локальный объект"*? После того как объект разрушен, ссылка указывает на мусор, который нельзя использовать

Comment: Это, должно быть, зависит от объекта. Если объект не имеет деструктора, то велика вероятность, что сразу за функцией, где он был локальной переменной, занятая им область стека ещё не перезаписана, а поля объекта пригодны для обработки. (До момента вызова следующей функции или определения новых переменных.) Возможно — не знаю специфики — во многопоточных приложениях такого везения нет.

Comment: Но я б один фиг не стал полагаться на возможность, от которой отговаривают все нормальные люди.

Comment: Чего Вы действительно хотите добиться? Ознакомьтесь с [ошибкой XY](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy).

Comment: Попытки строить код на "удачном" исходе из *undefined behavior* до добра не доводят.

Comment: Никакого *undef.behavior* не будет если знать C++. Компиляторы предупреждают, но не запрещают. Читайте http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134731/returning-a-const-reference-to-an-object-instead-of-a-copy#134777 и многое другое. **Просто запомнить что *ссылка на локальную переменную* всегда `const` и должна быть использована/скопирована/выброшена побыстрее.** Всё.

Comment: @kyb локальный объект уничтожается при выходе из блока. Поэтому как бы быстро Вы ни пытались его использовать вне этого блока по ссылке (не важно `const` или нет) будет UB, т.к. Вы пытаетесь использовать объект, которого уже нет. То, что осталось лежать в памяти по этому адресу уже не является живым дееспособным объектом.

Comment: @alexolut, почитайте https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/ , обратите внимание на год написания статьи. *Пусть ваша профессиональная уверенность немного пошатнётся и расширится мировоззрение )*

Comment: @kyb Вы не замечаете одной важной вещи. У Вас в сигнатуре функции возврат ссылки (`T&`), а у Саттера - значение (`T`).

Comment: @alexolut Значит я дурак уже несколько месяцев успешно юзаю under.beh. Хоть сам себе минусы ставь... (

Comment: Я бы на Вашем месте сформулировал **новый** вопрос из той части, которую Вы внесли редактированием. Задать новый вопрос ничего не стоит, а кардинально менять существующий - только усложняет ситуацию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объект будет создаваться ровно один раз и его можно запросто передавать в конструктор, не переживая за производительность.

```
virtual const Type& default_value() { 
    static const Type _default;
    return _default; 
}
```

Comment: Начиная с `c++11`

Comment: @alexolut, писать код на c++ < 11 в 2016 году это трата времени там, где можно съэкономить

Comment: @kyb вот когда метка добавлена в вопрос, то подобные комментарии уже не актуальны. А пока её не было, вполне имело смысл.

Comment: @alexolut, добавил её после вашего комментария. согласен.

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос довольно сумбурный, и как я уже высказался в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/569280/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-rvalue#comment746578_569280), порожден ошибкой XY, тем не менее попробую дать ответы.

1. Возврат ссылки на локальную переменную - есть UB (неопределенное поведение).
   Суть ошибки в том, что при выходе из блока объект уничтожается, и попытки обращения к такому "объекту" по сути равносильны чтению любого неинициализированного участка памяти, с той лишь разницей, что фактически там ещё могут быть следы уничтоженного объекта. А значит, наблюдаемое поведение программы вполне может казаться корректным, пока не проявится во всей "красе" в самый неподходящий момент.

   Современные компиляторы сообщают о попытке возврата ссылки на локальную переменную соответствующим предупреждением. [Пример](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/aZWc8IpF2YtJt8JF):

   ```
   int& f() {
       int i = 42; 
       return i;
   }
   ```

   > warning: reference to stack memory associated with local variable 'i' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]

   Т.о. нельзя допускать в коде подобных действий.
2. Для создания новых объектов как копии уже существующих можно использовать известный паттерн ["Прототип"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)). Возможно, он даст даже несколько больше, чем нужно для Вашей задачи. Основная суть в том, что возвращается объект, созданный копирующим конструктором из правильно созданного ранее и хранимого где-то долговременно (в смысле жизни программы) объекта. Например, это может быть реализовано как [предложил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/569298/176217) @int3, или в качестве члена класса (статического или нет, зависит от того сколько разных "прототипов" нужно иметь), или вовсе в глобальной переменной.
3. Чтобы избежать лишних копирований объекта (при возврате по значению) уже долгое время в компиляторах реализованы соответствующие подходы по оптимизации ([RVO/NRVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)). Но начиная с `c++11` для тяжеловесных классов имеет смысл реализовать перемещающие конструктор и оператор присваивания.

Comment: То бишь зря думать как облегчить передачу из этого разряда? class a { list<ptr> a; list<ptr> getA() return a } class b { a aIns; list<ptr> getB() return a.getA() } class c { b bins; void some() list<ptr> d = b.getB() }

Comment: @Meer задайте отдельным вопросом на сайте, код в комментариях совсем не воспринимается.